# Error de Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, eclipse

tengo un problema en java, quiero ejecutar un proceso batch pero me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No hay ningún error solo lo de la foto, lo que entiendo es que es problema de versión y pues anteriormente estaba compilando en java 8 y ya se lo cambié a java 7 pero ni así funciona, estoy usando eclipse para ejecutar el programa, espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, gracias.

Comment: Pues significa que tienes que actualizar hacia arriba, no hacia abajo.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando te sale ese error, suele significar que debes usar una versión *más reciente* de Java

Los números de versión mayor correspondientes a cada release son:

```
Java SE 18 = 62,
Java SE 17 = 61,
Java SE 16 = 60, 
Java SE 15 = 59,
Java SE 14 = 58,
Java SE 13 = 57,
Java SE 12 = 56,
Java SE 11 = 55,
Java SE 10 = 54,
Java SE 9 = 53,
Java SE 8 = 52,
Java SE 7 = 51,
Java SE 6.0 = 50,
Java SE 5.0 = 49,
JDK 1.4 = 48,
JDK 1.3 = 47,
JDK 1.2 = 46,
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

Así pues, prueba un upgrade, no un downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Si la librería de terceros ya esta compilada en una version de JDK superior no importa que cambies la JDK de tu proyecto a una inferior, porque eso solo cambia la compilación de tú código no de las librerías importadas.

Revisa tu POM y verifica que utilizas Log4j entre la Version 2.4 a la 2.12.1 que son las compatibles con Java 7, si tiene Log4j 2.13.0 o superior solo es compatible con Java 8 o superior.